# How to traverse through HTML and convert it to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, traversal

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="block" data-type="click">
    <div class="container" data-type="noclick">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container" data-type="noclick">
        <div class="container" data-type="noclick">
            <p data-type="click">More text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <p data-type="click">More text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
        ...
</div>
```

There is a parent element called `block` which may contain any number of child elements, of which may also contain any number of child elements itself.

I am using the following code to convert HTML into JSON output:

```
    site = [];
    ctr = 0;

    $(".block").each(function(){
        site.push([]);
        site[ctr]["type"] = $(this).data("type");
        site[ctr]["class"] = $(this).attr("class");
        site[ctr]["style"] = $(this).attr("style");
        site[ctr]["children"] = [];
            $(this).children().each(function(){
                site[ctr]["children"].push([]);
                site[ctr]["children"]["type"] = $(this).data("type");
                site[ctr]["children"]["class"] = $(this).attr("class");
                site[ctr]["children"]["style"] = $(this).attr("style");
            });
        ctr+=1;
    });
```

However, for an element that contains many different levels of child elements, what is the best approach to include those in the array?

In other words, the code above **only** works for elements that contain one level of children - how could I get it to work for an element that contains 20 different levels of children whilst another only contains two?

Comment: i will ask you to use [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie Those work on form elements, not any DOM element. Might want to read the pages you link to :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey  it will take less time to create hidden form there rather than traversing each parent and then it's child and then there child and so on and create array.

Comment: `site.push([]);` and `site[ctr]["children"].push([]);` why do you use (numerical) Arrays as dictionaries/objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follows a full working example using [vanilla javascipt](https://snipcart.com/blog/learn-vanilla-javascript-before-using-js-frameworks) and a [recursive function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-recursive-function/):

```js
function convertToArray(elements) {
    const array = [];
    
    if(!elements || elements.length === 0) {
        return [];
    }    
    
    for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        array[i] = {};
        array[i]['class'] = elements[i].getAttribute('class');
        array[i]['type'] = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
        array[i]['style'] = elements[i].getAttribute('style');
        array[i]['children'] = convertToArray(elements[i].children);
    }
    return array;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
console.log(convertToArray(rootElement));
```

```html
<div class="block" data-type="click">
    <div class="container" data-type="noclick">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container" data-type="noclick">
        <div class="container" data-type="noclick">
            <p data-type="click">More text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <p data-type="click">More text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```